# recognizing items in values list in R in for loop

Tags: r

I am having some trouble getting R to recognize items in my Values list (in RStudio) in a function call (just referring to it as a generic function here). Here's an example...the following works just fine if I type it in directly:

```
result <- function(cnv.chr1.S1, cnv.chr1.S2, cnv.chr1.S3)
```

because cnv.chr1.S1, cnv.chr1.S2, and cnv.chr1.S3 are objects (specifically GRanges objects) that I've created previously.

But as I'm looping over different chromosomes and there are really many more than 3 samples (S1, S2, S3), I've tried the following (simplified here)

```
chrom <- paste("chr", 1:1, sep = "")
sample.names <- paste("S", 1:3, sep = "")
for (thischrom in chrom)
{
  for (sample in sample.names)
  {
    a <- function(list(paste(paste("cnv", thischrom, sep = "."), sample.names, sep = ".")))
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't work because

```
paste(paste("cnv", thischrom, sep = "."), sample.names, sep = ".")
```

just creates a character list of items that have the same names as the items in my Values list. How do I get R to access the appropriate objects in my Values list?

Thanks for any thoughts you might have!

Steve

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
library(dplyr)

chrom <- paste("chr", 1:1, sep = "")
sample.names <- paste("S", 1:2, sep = "")

cnv.chr1.S1 = c(1, 2)
cnv.chr1.S2 = c(2, 3)

result = 
  data_frame(chrom = chrom) %>%
  merge(data_frame(sample.names = sample.names) ) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(object = 
           paste("cnv", chrom, sample.names, sep = ".") %>%
           parse(text = .) %>%
           eval %>%
           list)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it's not really what I'm getting at - its that the names I'm creating from the paste function does create the proper list of names, but R sees them as a list of items, rather than as referring to objects or variables that already have stored information in them.

Comment: Do you want to evaluate each item? See edit for away to do that